# Trying to get VBA code to copy over bold formatting?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, formatting

Here is my current implementation (this is a small section of a much longer script):

```
Dim j As Integer, q As Integer
q = 2
For j = 1 To 300
    If Sheet2.Cells(j, i).Value = "X" Then
    Sheet1.Cells(q, 4).Value = Sheet2.Cells(j, 3).Value
        If Cells(j, 3).Font.Bold = True Then
            Sheet2.Cells(j, 3).Copy
            Sheet1.Cells(q, 4).PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)
        End If
     q = q + 1
    End If
Next j
```

This code is looping through a range and finding values that have an X in another column, that's for something else. But I am trying to also get it to copy over specifically the bold formatting. This implementation "works" in that it runs, but confusingly, it only picks up on the bold formatting sometimes, and usually only the first bold entry in a group of bold entries.

I can't have it just copy over every single one, because while that works, it also runs slowly and is generally ugly. Maybe if I included a DoEvents = false it wouldn't be so bad, but still.

Comment: What's `i`?  How/where do you declare and define that?

Comment: It's defined elsewhere in the code and used to get the column, i functions as it should

Answer (score 0):

Because you're copying and pasting values elsewhere, it's generally a good idea to clear the clipboard after each copy.  This may also affect the performance (in a positive way).

Add the following code to immediately after your `PasteSpecial` line:

`Application.CutCopyMode = False`

Does the sheet contain any conditional formatting rules that may break?